# Variable Declaration issue in vb6

Tags: arrays, vb6

Well Its been a while that i have had my hands in vb6. I have been declaring variables as

```
dim a,b,c as integer
```

But, today, while writing a program consisting of arrays, the declaration

```
dim ar(10),i,a as integer
```

yielded a wrong result. Then I changed my declaration to

```
dim ar(10) as integer,i as integer, a as integer
```

and the code worked. What is the difference between these two types of declarations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You made an understandable error, one I have been caught with myself.  When declaring variables the comma starts a completely new declaration.

So

```
   dim ar(10),i,a as integer
```

is the same as

```
   dim ar(10)
   dim i
   dim a as integer
```

Which as you can see declares 'ar' as an array of variants and 'i' as a single variant.

I avoid using the comma in a dim - it is just too easy for it to go wrong.